# Writing custom validator to confirm email fields with formvalidator.net

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using the Jquery Form validation plugin from http://formvalidator.net. It works perfect, but however I have a little problem writing a custom validator to confirm/compare two email fields. In my form I have the "mEmail" field and "confirm_mEmail" field. I need a custom validator to confirm both email address to make sure they are identical.

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="mEmail" type="text" name="mEmail" size="50" data-validation="email"><br />
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<label>Confirm email :</label>
<input id="confirm_mEmail" type="text" name="confirm_mEmail" size="50" data-validation="email">    <br />
</div>
```

There is an example of custom validator at http://formvalidator.net, but I couldn't make one for what I am looking for.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, email validation is included ,but I am looking to confirm that the two email fields are identical. I have an "Email" and "Confirm email" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the password confimation system ?

```
Password confirmation
<p>
  Password (at least 8 characters)
  <input name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8">

  Confirm password
  <input name="pass" data-validation="confirmation">
</p>
```

and adapt it to

```
<p>
 email
  <input name="email_confirmation" data-validation="email" >

  Confirm email
  <input name="email" data-validation="confirmation">
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect. Works perfect with Password confirmation method. Thanks a million.